# showing a specific output on alertdialog based on what is saved in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

so yesterday i was introduced to sharedprefrences and started on building some code. I have a simple input where user inputs 3 string and 3 clock times.

So this is the quantity

```
String kolicina_main = sharedPreferences.getString("dnevna_kolicina",null);
```

It is basicly how many times a day you do something. And then:

```
String ura1_main = sharedPreferences.getString("ura1",null);
                       String ura2_main = sharedPreferences.getString("ura2",null);
                       String ura3_main = sharedPreferences.getString("ura3",null);
```

those are the 3 clocs the user sets.

Here is my problem. If for example user selects 1x time per day i want to display in alertdialog only the first time. If he selects 2x times per day i want to show clock1 and clock2.

So far if i am on the emulator and input data and select 3x time per day it shows 3 and if i select 2 times it shows 2. The problem is when i close the emulator and reopen and i click show data i get 0 clocks even if it says that i take 2x times per day.

Any ideas where i went wrong.

```
    public void viewAll(){

       pregled_nastavitev.setOnClickListener(
               new View.OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onClick (View view){
                       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("nastavitve_uporabnika", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                       String bolecina_main = sharedPreferences.getString("bolecina",null);
                       String zdravilo_main = sharedPreferences.getString("zdravilo",null);
                       String kolicina_main = sharedPreferences.getString("dnevna_kolicina",null);
                       String ura1_main = sharedPreferences.getString("ura1",null);
                       String ura2_main = sharedPreferences.getString("ura2",null);
                       String ura3_main = sharedPreferences.getString("ura3",null);

                       String bolecina_main1 = bolecina.getText().toString();
                       String zdravilo_main1 = zdravilo.getText().toString();
                       String kolicina_main1 = kolicina_zdravila.getText().toString();
                       String ura1_main1 = ura1.getText().toString();
                       String ura2_main1 = ura2.getText().toString();
                       String ura3_main1 = ura3.getText().toString();

                       if (bolecina_main == null && zdravilo_main == null && kolicina_main == null && ura1_main == null && ura2_main == null && ura3_main == null){
                                showMessage("Napaka","Ni najdenih podatkov!");
                           return;
                       }
                       else {
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                           buffer.append("Vaša bolečina: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("bolecina", "")+"\n");
                           buffer.append("Vaše zdravilo: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("zdravilo", "")+"\n");
                           buffer.append("Zdravilo vzamem: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("dnevna_kolicina", "")+" x dnevno!"+"\n");

                           if (kolicina_zdravila.getText().toString().equals("1")){
                               buffer.append("Prvič ob: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("ura1", "")+"\n");
                           }
                           if (kolicina_zdravila.getText().toString().equals("2")){
                               buffer.append("Prvič ob: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("ura1", "")+"\n");
                               buffer.append("Drugič ob: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("ura2", "")+"\n");
                           }
                           if (kolicina_zdravila.getText().toString().equals("3")) {
                               buffer.append("Prvič ob: " + sharedPreferences.getString("ura1", "") + "\n");
                               buffer.append("Drugič ob: " + sharedPreferences.getString("ura2", "") + "\n");
                               buffer.append("Tretjič ob: " + sharedPreferences.getString("ura3", "") + "\n");
                           }

                           showMessage("Vaši podatki",buffer.toString());
                   }
                   }
               }
       );


   }

   public void showMessage (String title, String message){

       AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setCancelable(true);
       builder.setTitle(title);
       builder.setMessage(message);
       builder.show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error myself. Was checking the wrong condition.

```
                  if (sharedPreferences.getString("dnevna_kolicina", "").toString().equals("1")){
                       buffer.append("Prvič ob: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("ura1", "")+"\n");

                   }
                   if (sharedPreferences.getString("dnevna_kolicina", "").toString().equals("2")){
                       buffer.append("Prvič ob: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("ura1", "")+"\n");
                       buffer.append("Drugič ob: "+ sharedPreferences.getString("ura2", "")+"\n");

                   }
                   if (sharedPreferences.getString("dnevna_kolicina", "").toString().equals("3")) {
                       buffer.append("Prvič ob: " + sharedPreferences.getString("ura1", "") + "\n");
                       buffer.append("Drugič ob: " + sharedPreferences.getString("ura2", "") + "\n");
                       buffer.append("Tretjič ob: " + sharedPreferences.getString("ura3", "") + "\n");

                   }
```